# php - how to access object passed through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript object like below

```
var customerinfo = {
            customer_name : $('#customer_name').val(),
            customer_address: $('#customer_address').val(),
            customer_city : $('#customer_city').val(),
            customer_state : $('#customer_state').val(),
            customer_zip : $('#customer_zip').val(),
        };
```

Then I try to pass that to php using $.ajax like below

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "../folder/file.php",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: {
                     'customerinfo' : customerinfo,
                    },
                    success:function(){
                         window.location = "file.php";
                    }
            })
```

In php I try to print the object out

```
 $customerinfo = json_decode($_POST['customerinfo']);
 print_r($customerinfo);
```

or

```
 $customerinfo = $_POST['customerinfo'];
 print_r($customerinfo);
```

I get `undefined index customerinfo`

I also tried to json.stringify in the javascript before passing it but get same error.

I found a very similar post such as 
[jquery ajax object array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346266/jquery-ajax-object-array-php) but I couldnt get the code to work either.I think the ajax was able to pass the data through, just I dont know how to decode it on the php side.

I know I could just post it from html submit button, but This is simplified testing for a larger issue where I want to pass object that have many objects inside of it using jquery.

if the javascript side is correct, the question is `"how to access objects passed through jquery ajax in PHP."`

if not, the question would be `"how to pass objects from javascript to php."`

Comment: `success:function(data){ doSomethingWith(data); }`

Comment: I am not trying to get a response from the php. I actually want to do a redirect. so I just put that in the success.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see the problem might be in the data.
try posting with static data, meaning replace the

```
var customerinfo = {
        customer_name : $('#customer_name').val(),
        customer_address: $('#customer_address').val(),
        customer_city : $('#customer_city').val(),
        customer_state : $('#customer_state').val(),
        customer_zip : $('#customer_zip').val(),
    };
```

with

```
var customerinfo = {
        customer_name : 'ddd',
        customer_address: 'ddd',
        customer_city : 'ddd',
        customer_state : 'ddd',
        customer_zip : 'ddd'
    };
```

also try sending the ajax from the browser console, that way you'll be able to see the data being posted